# Qual a convenção usada para organização das Views do Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de organizar as Views no Laravel, em qual diretório é melhor deixar os includes, templates e as views principais.

Também o que é melhor colocar nos includes (navbar? layouts? sidebar?) o que eu posso colocar como template? Estou aprendendo Laravel e ate agora só usei templates para fazer a estrutura padrão do HTML, nada mais que isso.

Answer (score 0):

Ao instalar o Laravel, ele já vem com as pastas já pré-configuradas. No caso, os layouts, views..

No geral, em layouts é costumeiro deixar tudo o que você tem de padrão nas páginas, por exemplo o navbar.

Na organização da view, segue o padrão MVC, no caso se você tiver um CRUD de usuário, você ao menos tem três views, list, create e edit. Então para cada controller cria-se uma pasta com as telas utilizadas pelo controller.

Mapa das pastas:

```
-views
   -usuarios
      -list.blade.php
      -edit.blade.php
   -categorias
      -list.blade.php
      -edit.blade.php
      -create.blade.php
```